# MS Graph, receive forbidden when try to add AndroidStoreApp

Tags: intune, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

I'm developing an application which will upload Android/IOS apps to InTune.
All works with LOB apps. I can add, list, update, delete.
However, when I try to add Android store app, I receive forbidden. I can list store apps, but not to add. From other hand, in Endpoint Manager, I can do this without any problems. All rights, needed and described in Microsoft Doc are set.

I use MS Graph v1.0.

Response which I receive:
An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 946f8683-f832-4431-83f5-e32c4d9a74a0 - Url: https://fef.amsub0502.manage.microsoft.com/AppLifecycle_2205/StatelessAppMetadataFEService/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps?api-version=2020-08-04

```
<ODataError xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.OData.Core">
<Details i:nil="true"/>
<ErrorCode>Forbidden</ErrorCode>
<InnerError i:nil="true"/>
<InstanceAnnotations/>
<Message>{ "_version": 3, "Message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 1f6c6323-57b0-44f3-9337-28f77a82763c - Url: https://fef.amsub0502.manage.microsoft.com/AppLifecycle_2205/StatelessAppMetadataFEService/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps?api-version=2020-08-04", "CustomApiErrorPhrase": "", "RetryAfter": null, "ErrorSourceService": "", "HttpHeaders": "{}" }</Message>
<Target i:nil="true"/>
</ODataError>
```

I use the same code to add for both:

```
AndroidStoreApp app ...
await GraphClient.DeviceAppManagement.MobileApps.Request().AddAsync(app).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Any advise please?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the right permissions set for the app, you'd need: DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All

You can decode the token at https://jwt.ms and make sure you have DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All permissions assigned.

Also, sample request json that worked for me is below:

```
{
    "owner": "",
    "fileName": "A_Online_Radio_1.0.5.4.apk",
    "description": "A Online Radio 1.0.5.4",
    "categories": [],
    "displayName": "A_Online_Radio_1.0.5.4.apk",
    "minimumSupportedOperatingSystem": {
        "v4_0": true
    },
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.androidLOBApp",
    "identityVersion": "10",
    "privacyInformationUrl": null,
    "notes": "",
    "informationUrl": null,
    "developer": "",
    "publisher": "A Online Radio",
    "identityName": "com.leadapps.android.radio.ncp",
    "isFeatured": false,
    "versionName": "1.0.5.4",
    "versionCode": "1",
    "packageId": "Package Id value"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've found a problem in my json.